# difference between react-native link and cocoapods?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

What does `react-native link` do?

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg doc says to do

```
react-native link react-native-svg
```

is it the same as

```
pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'  
# pod install
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cocoapods is the dependency manager for iOS. Just like npm is for JavaScript (more specifically Node.js) projects.

Let's switch the example to use `react-native-device-info`.

The project asks for you to create or add the following to a `Podfile` (if you're linking manually).

```
pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'
```

This will add `RNDeviceInfo` as an iOS dependency and will look inside of `'../node_modules/react-native-device-info'` to get it. More specifically it'll look for the [.podspec](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/blob/master/RNDeviceInfo.podspec) file.

If you take a look at the .podspec file, you'll see something like

`s.source_files  = "RNDeviceInfo/*.{h,m}"`. All the file is going to do is grab the matching sources (`RNDeviceInfo.h` and `RNDeviceInfo.m`) and store them inside of `RNDeviceInfo` directory. I think (total guess), the directory name matches `s.name`.

`react-native link ...` effectively does the same thing, automatically. I quote from React docs:

> Link your native dependencies: **react-native link**
>     Done! All libraries with native dependencies should be successfully linked to your iOS/Android project.

Both accomplish the same result, using `react-native link` will automate the linking of native libraries.

Comment: if you manual link a package do you need to also install it through Cocoapods?

Comment: Not necessarily @GabrielMoncea - you can either manually link it or (if the library gives you the option to) install it through Cocoapods. Never both.

Comment: Thank you! Cocoapods FTW

Comment: @Dan When I do `react-native link $package-name`, it adds a reference to my pod file too. Is this correct? Doesn't seem right that I'm installing via cocoa pods and via react-native link / node modules?

Answer (score 1):

Just like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45297691/10009300) said, `react-native link` add your dependencies in `cocoapods` `Podfile` for you automatically, if your ios project used `cocoapods`.

But it is not like this before `react-native v0.50.0`. It wrote dependencies' info ( `file reference`, `header search path`, `library`) into your project's `xcodeproj` directly. You still can see the old code in [react-native v0.57](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.57-stable/local-cli/link/ios/registerNativeModule.js).

So, why uses `cocoapods`?

I guess it's for **consistent package management**. Without `cocoapods`, if your dependency, named A, is dependent on another popular module B from iOS communtity , the author of A would need to write some script like `install-B.sh` to download B's files, or even worse add B into A project directly.

See [`ios-install-third-party.sh` in react-native v0.48](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.48-stable/scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh) for example.

Also, your iOS development colleagues would like to use `cocoapods`(rather than `xcodeproj`). **It is important to use the same package manager for javascript developers and iOS developers.** Both you know all native modules that your project includes.

`react-native link` with `cocoapods` can let we leverage the two communities.