# React Native: What is the difference between using Cocoapods and manually linking modules?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods, podfile

I've been working with React Native for about a year, and have always linked native modules either with `react-native link` or by manual linking, by dragging the `.xcodeproj` file to the Libraries folder and then dragging the `.a` file to the "Link Binary With Libraries" section of Build Phases. I'd heard of Cocoapods, and my project does include a Podfile (not sure where it came from), but it wasn't until recently that someone told me I HAD to use Cocoapods in order to link native modules, by doing `cd ios` + `pod install` etc.

**What I Want To Know:**

What's the difference between linking native modules the way I've done it all along, and doing it via Cocoapods? What's the essence of Cocoapods and how does it fit into React Native development vs regular linking?

Comment: This outlines it quite well https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/96

Comment: Please refer this stack overflow article. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45296994/difference-between-react-native-link-and-cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45296994/difference-between-react-native-link-and-cocoapods)

Answer (score 0):

1. For ***manually integrated module*** most cases you have to link some system files if library have some dependencies but for ***cocoa pod***  all dependencies liked automatically
2. For ***manually integrated module*** you need to update library manually but for cocoa pod you can it by just ***pod install*** command from ***terminal***
3. In which case which one is better? when your library need update frequently you should choice ***cocoa pod*** but when you want to modify a ***cocoa pod library*** you would choice it to integrated manually.

Comment: So for any given module, can you CHOOSE to incorporate it as either a manually integrated module or via cocoapods? Can you incorporate it using both ways?

Comment: cocoa pod is better

Comment: Noted, but my question was whether you can choose to incorporate it as either a manually integrated module or via cocoapods. I'm trying to understand conceptually the role that each has.

Comment: cocoa pod is preferred

Comment: Is it the case that they both seek to accomplish the same thing, but that Cocoapods does a better job? Or does each have a different goal that they're trying to accomplish?